# Invalid behavior of object.assign

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

Why does the following prints "222"?

```js
class MyClass {
  print() {
    console.log(111);
  }
}
const n = new MyClass();
const a = {
  print() {
    console.log(222);
  },
}
Object.assign(a, new MyClass());
a.print();
```

Comment: `print` exists on `n`'s prototype. _"`Object.assign()` static method copies all **enumerable** **own properties** from one or more source objects to a target object."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: The question should be closed because it's based on an incorrect understanding of `Object.assign` rather than the method functioning incorrectly or there being a question related to any of its specificities.

Comment: It looks like this is a convoluted way of creating a "parent" class for `a`, and as `a` has an implementation override, it takes precedence. `new MyClass()` doesn't have any properties, but it does have a `prototype`.

Comment: oh, and it looks like there's a duplicate.

Comment: `n` is never assigned.